# How to implement decreasing Gatling users during some time without spikes in users arrival?

Tags: scala, gatling

I have the ramp down test that decrease the amount of users every time in Gatling. For example, 5 users every 1 minute, from 15 users to 5 users. For the user's injections I use constantConcurrentUsers():

```
setUp(
   Test.inject(
      (15) to  5 by (-5)
        .map(i => constantConcurrentUsers(i) during 60)
    )
```

[Screenshot with constantConcurrentUsers()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6e4L.png) 
But users arrive with some spikes. I want it to be more constant like in atOnceUsers() where we don't have any spikes. Is there another way to do it in Gatling?

Answer (score 0):

> But users arrive with some spikes.

This is just a consequence of this chart displaying "active users" metric, not "concurrent users" one. See [doc](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/reports/#active-users-over-time).

Comment: yes, thank you. So that is why I would like to implement it using the open model. But I can't find the way how to stop previous running users for the next step and decrease them. Is there way to do it?

Comment: No, the injection profile only controls when new users are started. It can't abort them.

Comment: thank you, but can we set up it inside the loop of scenario somehow?